# Radio Button selection using Javascript executor

Tags: javascript, selenium, radio-button, executor

I am trying the select the 'Yes' 'No' options in a page,as normal 'Click()' is not working I have used JSExecutor for this! The problem is it is selecting the options, but the value was never sent as input, and the application is throwing error when I tried to continue.

Tried xpath's in diff ways!

```
WebElement st_1 = driver.findElement(By.id("app-select-no"));
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].checked = true;", st_1);
```

Below is HTML

```
div class="form-group input-form-group col-xs-6">
<input id="app-select-no" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="radio" ng-value="false" ng-model="openAccount.abc" required="" name="affRadioGroup" value="false" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false"/>
<label class="field-label-radio text-bold active" ng-class="{active : openAccount.abc==false}" for="app-select-no">
<span translate-once="NO_BUTTON">No</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I didn't get this part " but the value was never sent as input", can you elaborate on that? You are saying that the option is being selected, but I'm not getting what is the problem. Can you also post the exception thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see If I understood, you are trying to select "yes" or "no" on that element, but I see that the element you are clicking is an input. You also need to send the "value" to the input besides clicking the element.

Im guessing that your problem is not the click with the executeScript, but you can also try this:

```
WebElement st_1 = driver.findElement(By.id("app-select-no"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", st_1 );
```

And to send a Value to that input, yo need to do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("st_1")).sendKeys("value here");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The input is just a radio button, so sendkeys should not be required. If we just apply javascript .checked=true, it should work, But we needed to put a wait before executing the javascript. Have posted the answer.

Comment: that's right,  I didn't see the @type attribute on the html.

Comment: Using JavaScript Executor I am able to select the radio button, but the option is not rendering in the back end which doesn't allow me to move from that page! @Satish: I have used wait as well.

Comment: @Joe this code is selecting the radio button, now how that information is being passed from UI to backend , really depends on the design. From Selenium, we can only make sure that radio button is getting selected. Try to use 2nd option using webelement method and putting wait after that : wait until radio button is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the wait for element before executing the javascript solved the problem. Here is the working code for both using javascript and without javascript(using webelement click):

```
driver.get("file:///home/sgupta/Desktop/a.html");
    WebElement radio = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input#app-select-no")));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver.getDriver();
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].checked=true", radio);
```

Using WebElement method :

```
driver.get("file:///home/sgupta/Desktop/a.html");
WebElement radio = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input#app-select-no")));
radio.click();
```